# How to add alternative app names to improve searchability of app on device (not App Store or Google Play, just search on phone)

Tags: android, ios, search

I've got my app name written in cyrillic alphabet. My goal is for users to be able to find it also by latin transliteration.
For example: find app called "Сбербанк" by typing "Sberbank".
I am not talking about web search, only local search on user's device.
I am using Flutter to develop my app.

Closest thing I've found is [this](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/sirikit/registering_custom_vocabulary_with_sirikit/specifying_synonyms_for_your_app_name), but is it necessary to involve Siri? Can't I just specify some keywords for on-device search? And what can I do with android?